# Change background color of html page with python

Tags: python

Is it impossible to change the background color of a page, for example, on the Google home page, its possible to change the color from white to a black ?
When I run a script and refresh the Google page, the background color is converted to black and when the script is closed, it returns to its natural color

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not impossible. But you can't change permanently a page with a script. If you shut down the script, the changes won't stay.

To do what you want, you need to make a extension for your browser. But I'm not sure if python is the best language to do that or if it can to that.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, I have an idea for one of the sites. I want to temporarily convert the Dark Mode page. When I run the script, the page turns black, What do I need to do this

Comment: Ah, ok. Now i understand what you want. I will edit and answer your question.